# Setting User Agent of URLClassLoader

Tags: java, user-agent, urlclassloader

Alright, so.  I have my own website with a applet loaded in a jar.  I want to use a java program to load the jar through a URLClassLoader, and start the applet that way.

I'm using this code:

```
classLoader =  new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("http:/foo.com/applet.jar")});
                    applet = (Applet) classLoader.loadClass(code).newInstance();
```

It generates 403 errors, but when I check the error log on my website, it doesn't show that anyone 403'd.

Why is java outputting 403 errors, when my website log isn't?
If I open a urlconnection, and set the user agent, it works, but if I don't, it 403's.

So I was wondering, how can I set the user agent so the URLClassLoader doesn't error out.
or is there another way to load the applet jar without having to download it on the user's PC?

Comment: Spoofed the URL, it's not my real website.

Comment: So should we put 'spoofed' answers?  Show the correct URL if you want my help..

Comment: I tried to point out you are missing a slash, and it is one of the important ones...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader%28java.net.URL%5B%5D,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory%29):

```
URLClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent, URLStreamHandlerFactory factory)
```

By overriding some stuff in the `factory`, you should be able to set the user agent before it establishes a URL connection.